# PHP - I have two functions that work together, but that now gives me an error, that before it wasn't there

Tags: php

Now they aren't working anymore, but before they were

```
function perm1($conn)
{
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, 'SELECT * FROM nivel_acesso');
$success = odbc_execute($stmt);
echo "erro 1";
echo '<ul class="perm">';
echo "erro 2";
while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array($stmt))
{
echo "erro 3";
    $rows = $myRow;
    echo '<li>';
    echo "erro 4";
    echo'<input type="checkbox" name="perm'.$rows["nivel"].'" value="'.$rows["nivel"].'"><label for="perm'.$rows["nivel"].'">'.mb_convert_encoding($rows["descricao"], 'utf8', 'latin1').'</label>';
    echo '</li>';
    echo "erro 5";
}
echo "erro 6";
echo '</ul>';
echo "erro 7";
if(empty($rows))
{
    echo "erro 8";
    return $nada = "macacos";
    echo "erro 9";
}

echo "erro 10";
return $rows;
}
```

That's my function to show a group of checkboxes with a list of permissions from my database, the query is fine and the connection to.

```
function utf8_converter($array){
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
    if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
        $item = utf8_encode($item);
    }
});
return $array;
}
```

That's my function that I use to get the utf-8 of the inputs I get from the database.

When I use something like `utf8_converter(perm1($conn))` it gives me this error:

**Warning**: array_walk_recursive() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in [Directory of the file here + file name].php on **line 35**

**Line 35** is:

```
function utf8_converter($array){
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
    if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
        $item = utf8_encode($item);
    }
});<--This one here
return $array;
}
```

Comment: Apparently $array is not an array. What is perm($conn)?

Comment: @cjs1978 perm1 is the same as perm, Edited, now they are equal, perm($conn) is the first function I show you there.

Comment: Did you just turn on error reporting? The call to `utf8_converter` does nothing because the return is discarded. None of makes much sense really

Comment: You are aware that at this point your `$rows` variable contains only a single row, right? And what kind of content are you dealing with here, that you have to do encoding conversion on the fly?

Comment: And btw., this is a really shitty question title. Please go read [ask].

Comment: @Steve Yes, I've turned on error reporting, that's where I get the **Warning**: array_walk_recursive() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in [Directory of the file here + file name].php on line 35

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, That was the best title I could get with this shitty error because yesterday it was working

Comment: @CBroe i domnt think the function ever returns `$rows`, it returns the string `macacos`

Comment: @CBroe Weird, because yesterday it was working perfectly fine, and today it stopped working, no one messed with any of those functions nor the place it's called to work

Comment: Because the while loop will end when `$rows` is falsy, triggering the `if(empty($rows))` block

Comment: @Steve they assign `$rows = $myRow` first in the while loop, so it should contain the data of the last row after the loop, and therefor likely not be empty.

Comment: @Steve the loop ends when $myRow becomes false, different variable.

Comment: @CBroe are yes, missed that. Great variable naming...

Comment: @Steve It wasn't me nor my partner who named that way, I got that code from another person which I don't even know who is, sorry about the naming, we got few time to work at this so, we maintained the same variable names.

Comment: are you still getting all the html and echos before the error? If not the query isnt returning any results, which means `perm1` returns a string, hence the error. If you are seeing the html and echos, i have no idea.

Comment: @Steve Yes, but thanks for all the help, the page is working fine now. I don't know what happened, but it is

Comment: Sounds like you're going to end up with a very solid and easy to maintain application right there.

Comment: @domdom That will not be my problem ^-^